# Get memory usage per domain in Varnish

Tags: linux, memory, varnish

I have a Varnish cache on my server and have 5 different domains on it. I can get the total memory usage of Varnish with varnishstat and top. But I want to know how much memory is occupied for each domain in Varnish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you run each domain on a separate varnish process, there is no available method to split it by domain

Comment: Great. So there is a way to do that. Can I run seperate varnish processes in varnish 4.1.1? or I need an upgared to 5.x? and may you please refer me a link to do this?

Comment: Have a look at https://ispire.me/running-multiple-instances-of-varnish-using-systemd/

Comment: Works fine on varnish 4

Answer (score 1):

This won't give you the exact memory, rather the cache usage per domain.

Run `varnishd`, specifying multiple storages:

```
varnishd -s domain1=malloc,1G -s domain2=malloc,2G ...
```

In your VCL, set the storage based on the domain:

```
sub vcl_backend_response {
    if (bereq.http.host == "domain1.example.com") {
        set beresp.storage = domain1;
    } else if {
        set beresp.storage = domain2;
    }
}
```

then you can then use:

```
varnishstat  -1 -f SMA.domain1.g_bytes -f SMA.domain1.g_space
varnishstat  -1 -f SMA.domain2.g_bytes -f SMA.domain2.g_space
```

to see how much space is used (`g_bytes`) and available (`g_space`) for each store.

Comment: that's great. I will give it a try. one question: what happen if I add or remove domains frequently? I mean should I restart after each domain addition or remove or a reload is enough?

Comment: sadly you will need to restart for that